# how to get the path of an installed npm package via npm CLI/API?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

i'm writing an npm script, which is packed as an npm package, exposing the main executable to `node_modules/.bin` to its hosting project.

this script has its own npm dependencies, and as the script flow relies on copying one of these dependencies to a different location, it needs to know where was that dependency installed.

how can i find (via API or the npm CLI) where was that dependency installed inside the host's `node_modules`?

Comment: thanx, @ParveenSachdeva, i couldn't find any similar questions when i posted this

Comment: @ParveenSachdeva, note that the linked question doesn't have any good answers on this, and also, mine refers to using the npm CLI/API (edited the title to reflect this)

Comment: @ParveenSachdeva, you convinced me - this is a duplicate. i posted a more elaborated answer on the linked post, and i'm marking this question as a duplicate

Comment: yeah I just checked and marked that as useful :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**see [a more elaborated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40504354/547020). this answer is kept for reference.**

---

you can use [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) with the [`--parseable`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls#parseable) flag, which will:

> Show parseable output instead of tree view.

for example:

```
$ npm ls my-dep -p
/Users/my-user/dev/host-project/node_modules/my-dep
```

be aware that the output may contain some irrelevant errors as well (e.g. about extraneous installations) — to work around this, activate the `--silent` flag (see [`loglevel`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel) in the docs):

```
$ npm ls my-dep -ps
```

you can integrate this command into your script using a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), in which case it's preferred to run the command *without the `--silent` flag* to allow capturing any error.

if an error is caught, you can then decide whether it's fatal or not (e.g. the aforementioned error about extraneous package should be ignored).